# Store and retrieve text online/cloud using python APIs

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, cloud

I am writing an python application which reads/parses a file of this this kind.

### myalerts.ini,

```
value1=1
value2=3
value3=10
value4=15
```

---

Currently I store this file in local filesystem. If I need to change this file I need to have physical access to this computer.

I want to move this file to cloud so that I can change this file anywhere (another computer or from phone).

If this application is running on some machine I should be able to change this file on the cloud and the application which is running on another machine which I don't have physical access to will be able to read updated file.

Notes,
I am new to both python and aws.
I am currently running it on my local mac/linux and planning on deploying on aws.

Comment: Unfortunately, your question is rather vague and therefore we cannot provide any specific advice. What do you mean by "an application which requires to store and retrieve data on the cloud using APIs" -- is this just a school assignment, or is it an actual application you are developing? Feel free to Edit your question to provide additional information such as exactly what you are trying to accomplish, what you have tried so far and what difficulties you have encountered. For tips on asking a good question, please see: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @JohnRotenstein, Github link for the application I am working on,
https://github.com/garanaveen/arbitrage
Please don't bash me for the quality of code. I am still trying to learn python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many options!

- [Amazon S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Welcome.html): This is the simplest option. Each computer could download the file at regular intervals or just before they run a process. If the file is big, the app could instead check whether the file has changed before downloading.
- [Amazon Elastic File System (EFS)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/whatisefs.html): If your applications are running on multiple Amazon EC2 instances, EFS provides a shared file system that can be mounted on each instance.
- [Amazon DynamoDB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Introduction.html): A NoSQL database instead of a file. Much faster than parsing a file, but less convenient for updating values — you'd need to write a program to update values, eg from the command-line.
- [AWS Systems Manager Parameter Store](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-paramstore.html): A managed service for storing parameters. Applications (anywhere on the Internet) can request and update parameters. A great way to configure cloud-based application!

If you are looking for minimal change and you want it accessible from anywhere on the Internet, **Amazon S3** is the easiest choice.

Whichever way you go, you'll use the [boto3 AWS SDK for Python](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html).